# Requiring OpenMP availability for use in an Rcpp package

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, armadillo, r-package

I have prepared a package in R by using `RcppArmadillo` and `OpenMP` libraries and following commands:

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("mypackage")
compileAttributes(verbose=TRUE)
```

Also, in the `DESCRIPTION` file I added:

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.12.8), RcppArmadillo
LinkingTo:Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
Depends: RcppArmadillo
```

and in the `NAMESPACE` file I added:

```
import(RcppArmadillo)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
```

Then I run the following codes in `cmd`:

```
R CMD build mypackage
R CMD INSTALL mypackage.tar.gz
```

I build and install the package in my computer and I use it now. But my colleges and friends are not able to install the package. The error messages is about `RcppArmadillo` and `OpenMP`libraries.

For instance:

> fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

Does anyone have previous experience in this case? Which type of settings I have to do in my package for solving this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Congratulations! You've *most likely* stumbled across macOS' lack `OpenMP` support. [This has been documented in the Rcpp FAQ as entry 2.10.3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf#page=7).

---

### Defensive coding

The reason for the error being apparent is you did not protect the `OpenMP` code appropriately... e.g.

Header inclusions are protected with:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif
```

Code has protections given by:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
   // multithreaded OpenMP version of code
#else
   // single-threaded version of code
#endif
```

This assumes you are *not* using the preprocessor `#omp` tags but more indepth omp function calls. If it is the prior, then the code protection is not important as the preprocessor tags will be discarded.

[(For those long time users of the above macro schemes coming here, please note that as of R 3.4.0, the `SUPPORT_OPENMP` definition was removed completely in favor of `_OPENMP`.)](https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2017/01/02)

---

### Creating a package requirement for `OpenMP` via `configure.ac`

However, the above is just good *defensive* coding. If your package requires a specific feature, then it may be time to consider using an `autoconf` file called `configure.ac` to generate a `configure` script.

Place the `configure.ac` in the top level of your package.

```
packagename/
|- data/
|- inst/
|- man/
|- src/
   |- Makevars
   |- HelloWorld.cpp
|- DESCRIPTION
|- NAMESPACE
|- configure.ac
|- configure
```

The `configure.ac` should contain the following:

```
AC_PREREQ(2.61)

AC_INIT(your_package_name_here, m4_esyscmd_s([awk -e '/^Version:/ {print $2}' DESCRIPTION]))
AC_COPYRIGHT(Copyright (C) 2017 your name?)


## Determine Install Location of R
: ${R_HOME=$(R RHOME)}
if test -z "${R_HOME}"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not determine R_HOME.])   
fi

## Setup RBin
RBIN="${R_HOME}/bin/R"
CXX=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CXX`
CPPFLAGS=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CPPFLAGS`
CXXFLAGS=`"${RBIN}" CMD config CXXFLAGS`

## Package Requires C++
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_REQUIRE_CPP

## Compiler flag check
AC_PROG_CXX

## Borrowed from BHC/imager/icd/randomForest
# Check for OpenMP 
AC_OPENMP 

# since some systems have broken OMP libraries
# we also check that the actual package will work
ac_pkg_openmp=no
if test -n "${OPENMP_CFLAGS}"; then
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([OpenMP detected, checking if viable for package use])
  AC_LANG_CONFTEST([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <omp.h>]], [[ return omp_get_num_threads (); ]])])
  "$RBIN" CMD SHLIB conftest.c 1>&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD 2>&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD && "$RBIN" --vanilla -q -e "dyn.load(paste('conftest',.Platform\$dynlib.ext,sep=''))" 1>&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD 2>&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD && ac_pkg_openmp=yes
  AC_MSG_RESULT([${ac_pkg_openmp}])
fi

# if ${ac_pkg_openmp} = "yes" then we have OMP, otherwise it will be "no"
if test "${ac_pkg_openmp}" = no; then 
  AC_MSG_WARN([No OpenMP support. If using GCC, upgrade to >= 4.2. If using clang, upgrade to >= 3.8.0])
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Please use a different compiler.])   
fi 

# Fin
AC_OUTPUT
```

To generate the `configure` script, run:

```
autoconf
```

Once this is done, you will need to rebuild your package. Note, you may need to install `autoconf` if on [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/autoconf.htm) and on macOS you likely need to install it via [homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Autoconf).

---

### Helping users get a viable `OpenMP` compiler

Now, you may want to ensure your colleagues are able to get the speedup gain from your `OpenMP`-enabled code.  To do so, one must enable `OpenMP` by having your colleagues shift away from using the default system compiler to either a "true" `gcc` or a viable `omp` enabled `clang` compiler.

Instructions for both on macOS are given here:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/

Comment: Auto-upvote triggered :)   In short, OpenMP is very easy on Linux, and not so much anywhere else.

Comment: @coatless thanks for your complete answer. I think you assume my OS is mac but it is Win 7. Since it is my first experience in R for building a package , some part of your answer is not clear for me. I couldn't understand where I should use 'configure.ac'. It seems it is not easy to follow this answer in win7 or maybe I am not able.

Comment: @ham82, the assumption was your colleagues' OS was macOS. I've updated the post to clarify the other concerns

Comment: @coatless in this scenario when you make a package out of the Rcpp code, should I not use // [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]] anymore? I was thinking it would look like #ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
  // [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#endif

Comment: @JCWong, you need to set `PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` in `src/Makevars`. `Rcpp::plugins` is meant more for inline code not package-level options.

Comment: @coatless when I try to access your link http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/ it says "Access denied."