# RcppEigen Multithreading

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

[Eigen supports OpenMP](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) for some matrix operations

It asks the user to set the `-fopenmp` flag on the compiler. When using RcppEigen and sourceCpp(), I see options like -DNDEBUG and -O2 optimization flags being passed, but I don't see -fopenmp. Is there a function that exposes this flag when compiling RcppEigen code?

Comment: There are plugins you can activate (or, in package, compiler flags you can set in `src/Makevars`). See the Rcpp Gallery questions on OpenMP.

Comment: Got it, looks like the answer is ```#include <omp.h>``` followed by ```// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]```. This is a great solution; if I turn my cpp code into a package a user doesn't have to think about passing openmp flags. I was worried end users would have to do something special to also get the flag passed in their system

Comment: Correct.  But you really want it in a package where you'd use `src/Makevars`.

Comment: And if you want to require openmp for a package you should see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280628/requiring-openmp-availability-for-use-in-an-rcpp-package/42281495#42281495

Comment: Or simply never mention the package to any macOS user :)