# Creating a R package requirement for OpenMP via configure.ac in windows

Tags: r, package, openmp, rcpp

I am working on my package in R, and I considered the following link about package requirement for OpenMP:
[[Requiring OpenMP availability for use in an Rcpp package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280628/requiring-openmp-availability-for-use-in-an-rcpp-package?rq=1][1])

In this link,there is some contents about package requirement for OpenMP via configure.ac. Since I am a Windows 7 user, I want to know how I can build my `configure` and `configure.ac` files in windows. I think it is easy for linux or mac users, but this step is not clear in Windows.

Comment: There is autoconf for Windows and hence no configure.ac for Windows.

Comment: "No" missing: There is NO autoconf for Windows...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So,how I can build the configure.ac file for my package in windows7? Does it have influence on package running time? Without this file, my package works fine, but its running time is not as good as its source code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks, I used your setting for makevars file in your winsorize package and now my package works fine.

Comment: Good to know.  Glad it helped.